# Is a folder with copied mysql tables resusable?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have a database in WAMPServer with quite some tables. They are in a folder called data. Within that folder, there are the folders of the databases with the tables.

Supposing I just copied this data folder and saved it on another device, a USB or whatever for security reasons (my computer is not that young anymore), would that be enough to reuse it if I needed to reinstall WAMP? The idea is to just insert the copied folder with the data back if needed. Could I run into issues with that solutions (future versions etc.)?

Comment: It would be a BETTER IDEA to just use phpMyAdmin to Backup (EXPORT) the database so you would be able to RESTORE it anywhere and to any version

Comment: Doing as YOU suggested... YES you WOULD have issues moving this database between versions

Comment: [See the WAMPServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) For details

Comment: Or [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Answer (score 2):

In case your database is in MyISAM format, it should be reusable, even for future versions.  Thought, you may need to run [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html) on your tables after copying them to newer version of MySQL.

For InnoDB databases, file-based backup/restore is also possible: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-backup.html

Comment: Just because there are folders in the data folder does NOT mean that the database is MYISAM. There are also folders created in the data folder for INNODB databases

Comment: @AlexM said "there are the folders of the databases with the tables", I assume this means folders named after databases with files named after tables inside.

Comment: Yes it does. But you also get folders named after the tables in there when you create INNODB databases. They just contain different information

Comment: If the OP has not considered doing a _simple_ backup(export), then suggesting using `mysql_update` will blow his tiny mind. Very unlikely he will be able to wrap his head round that

Comment: No need to argue with a tiny mind, it would be already enough to assume that I am just not that versed yet, for the most part self-taught. Comments like that are just condescending. It's just about two to three weeks that I have dealt with the database stuff.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Thank you, I will look into that.